# How can i change the size of iframe?

Tags: iframe, responsive

I tried to change this iframe size -

```html
<iframe src="http://gombit.net/plugins/mediaplayer/site/_embed.php?u=74Y" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" webkitAllowFullScreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

, but it don't woking. I want make responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below.

```
<iframe src="http://gombit.net/plugins/mediaplayer/site/_embed.php?u=74Y" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" webkitAllowFullScreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowFullScreen="true" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
```

In small device media make height auto.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap iframe in a block element, set the iframe as `absolute` and the block `relative`. Details in Snippet:

#### SNIPPET

```css
.frm {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
iframe {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure id='F1' class='frm'>
  <iframe id='I1' name='I1' src='http://gombit.net/plugins/mediaplayer/site/_embed.php?u=74Y' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowfullscreen width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>
</figure>
```

Wow it looks cool and it has no trouble complying with resize, nice.